# ng-flow.js, flow.js - Angular File Upload

Tags: angularjs, flow-js

I am able to use the wonderful ng-flow.js. But I am unable to post additional String Value along with file

Please tell me how can i post additional data along with the file in ng-flow.js

Comment: Do you means you can't upload file with that ng-flow.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can set options using config and pass a string value in query see below

```
    <div flow-init="config">
    </div>


    function FilesCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.config = {
        query: {flowParamName: value}
    } 
  }
```

Comment: please suggest some another way. I think once you initialized the flow then u cant change the config from controller...

Comment: can you post your code of what you tried and what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: below is what i am taking about.

If i am currently on employee page then file upload post target url should be 'mydomain/employee'
and If i am currently on user page then file upload post target url should be 'mydomain/user'

or please guide me how to post at least one string along with file so that i can differentiate.

Comment: have you found a solution ? i have the same problem. I want to send dynamic parameter, but once flow is initialized config can not be updated...

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following
 `<div flow-init="config"></div>`
Then

```
$scope.config = {
    query: function() {
        return {param: 'param value'}//your params, function will be called on every request
    }
}
```